# Can't access data from a table in a web page

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access content from the table from this page http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings# but however when I do so using beautiful soup in python, I am getting the data but from the 'All' filter selection not from a certain club filter. How can I achieve my goal?

I need to access all data from the table corresponding to a club in the filter. Please help me.

Please see the image below.

[image]

and also data from all pages:

[image]

I have used the following code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import lxml.html
import xlwt
import unicodedata
infoList = []

lLink = "http://www.afl.com.au/afl/stats/player-ratings/overall-standings#club/CD_T140"
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req_for_players = urllib2.Request(lLink,headers=header)
page_for_players = urllib2.urlopen(req_for_players)
soup_for_players = BeautifulSoup(page_for_players)

table = soup_for_players.select('table.player-ratings')[0]
for group_header in table.select('tbody tr span'):
    player = group_header.string
    infoList.append(player)
print infoList
```

The list `infoList` thus generated contains data corresponding to the "All" filter. But I want data according to the filter I choose.

Comment: You are going to need to show some code if you want useful answers.

Comment: I have added the code that I have used.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to parse the table - use Firebug or any similar tool to watch the response while clicking on some page in paginator and you'll see that it serves you the data in JSON! Pure win!!!

There you can see the URL format for JSON data:

```
http://www.afl.com.au/api/cfs/afl/playerRatings?roundId=CD_R201401411&pageSize=40&pageNum=2
```

and this way you can fetch even the first page of data without parsing HTML and maybe you can fetch all data at once by setting some high value to `pageSize` variable

Comment: What you mean? Chrome has Developer Tools, Firefox has Developer Tools, Opera has Firefly or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

When the page loads the first time, all the players are there in the table regardless of what filter you've chosen. The filter is only invoked a short while later. That is why you are getting data on all the players.

Underneath the page is calling the following when the filter is invoked:

```
http://www.afl.com.au/api/cfs/afl/playerRatings?roundId=CD_R201401411&teamId=CD_T140&pageSize=40&pageNum=1
```

to get one team's players. `CD_T140` are the Western Bulldogs in this case. You can see the different possible values in the `selLadderTeam` select element. You cannot simply call this url however as you will get a 401 error. Looking at the headers that are sent across, there is one that stands out. A token seems to be required. So using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) library (it's more user-friendly than urllib2) you can do the following:

```
>>> import requests
>>> url = "http://www.afl.com.au/api/cfs/afl/playerRatings?roundId=CD_R201401411&teamId=CD_T40&pageSize=100"
>>> h = {'x-media-mis-token':'e61767b39a7680235476bb33aa946c0e'}
>>> r = requests.get(url, headers=h)
>>> r
<Response [200]>
>>> j = r.json()
>>> len(j['playerRatings'])
45
>>> j['playerRatings'][0]
{u'roundId': u'CD_R201401411', u'player': {u'playerId': u'CD_I260257', u'playerName': {u'givenName': u'Scott', u'surname': u'Pendlebury'}, u'captain': False, u'playerJumperNumber': None}, u'draftYear': u'2005', u'detailedRatings': [{u'trend': u'NO_CHANGE', u'ranking': 2, u'ratingType': u'OVERALL', u'ratingPoints': 674}, {u'trend': u'NO_CHANGE', u'ranking': 1, u'ratingType': u'TEAM', u'ratingPoints': 674}, {u'trend': u'NO_CHANGE', u'ranking': 2, u'ratingType': u'POSITION', u'ratingPoints': 674}], u'team': {u'teamId': u'CD_T40', u'teamName': u'Collingwood', u'teamAbbr': u'COLL', u'teamNickname': u'Magpies'}, u'position': u'MIDFIELDER'}
>>> j['playerRatings'][44]
{u'roundId': u'CD_R201401411', u'player': {u'playerId': u'CD_I295012', u'playerName': {u'givenName': u'Matt', u'surname': u'Scharenberg'}, u'captain': False, u'playerJumperNumber': None}, u'draftYear': u'2013', u'detailedRatings': [{u'trend': u'NO_CHANGE', u'ranking': 0, u'ratingType': u'OVERALL', u'ratingPoints': 0},{u'trend': u'NO_CHANGE', u'ranking': 0, u'ratingType': u'TEAM', u'ratingPoints': 0}, {u'trend': u'NO_CHANGE', u'ranking': 0, u'ratingType': u'POSITION', u'ratingPoints': 0}], u'team': {u'teamId': u'CD_T40', u'teamName': u'Collingwood', u'teamAbbr': u'COLL', u'teamNickname': u'Magpies'}, u'position': u'MEDIUM_DEFENDER'}
>>>
```

Notes: I don't know exactly what roundID is. I increased pageSize to something that would likely return all of a team's players and removed pageNum. They could change the token at any time.